# Using splat operator in terraform azurerm_monitor_metric_alert scope setting

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I'm trying to setup an azurerm_monitor_metric_alert for my app services, I'd like to define one alert which covers all my app services which terraform is building.

I have two dimensions to my app services that are build, one based on regions (max of two) and the other on the number of app services deployed to each app service plan (unknown number, two in the below example).

I'd hoped I could do something like:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "disk1" {
  name                = "AppService-diskSpace-Sev1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.location1[0].name
  scopes              = ["${azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id}","${azurerm_app_service.location2.*.id}"]
  description         = "Disk space over 90 percent"
  window_size         = "PT6H"
  frequency           = "PT1H"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    metric_name      = "FileSystemUsage"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 241591910400 # 90% of 250Gb in bytes
  }
  severity         = 1
}
```

But I get an error like:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ..\..\..\infra\terraform\global\web\main.tf line 343, in resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "disk1":
 343:   scopes              = ["${azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id}","${azurerm_app_service.location2.*.id}"]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_app_service.location is tuple with 2 elements
    | azurerm_app_service.location2 is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "scopes": element 0: string required.
```

I've tried a number of different options but all produce errors, the doc says

> "A set of strings of resource IDs at which the metric criteria should be applied"

but I'm not sure what a "set of strings" means in this context.

-- EDIT
After comments below I tried what I hoped was being suggested but I'm still getting errors:

```
concat(azurerm_app_service.location.*.id)
```

returns

```
Error: scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declared.
```

```
["${azurerm_app_service.location.*.id}"]
```

returns

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "scopes": element 0: string required.
```

```
"${azurerm_app_service.web.*.id}"
```

returns

```
Error: scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declare
```

Comment: `${azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id}` is a list of IDs so `[${azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id}, ...]` creates a list of lists. You don't need the extra brackets and can just join the 2 lists with the `concat` function.

Comment: afraid I still can't get this to work: `concat(azurerm_app_service.location.*.id)` returns `Error: scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declared`. `["${azurerm_app_service.location.*.id}"]` returns `Inappropriate value for attribute "scopes": element 0: string required.`. `"${azurerm_app_service.web.*.id}"` returns `Error: scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declare`

Comment: You should edit your question to include everything you've tried.

Comment: I've tried many many different things which aren't working, I don't see huge value in littering my question with failed examples, I just need an example of what should work and I can go from there.

Comment: You just tried to reply with that but in a basically unreadable way. You should edit the question instead of commenting with blocks of code or error messages. From the comment it's hard to make out whether you actually tried to concatenate 2 lists or you just passed the one list in which is not how the function works (and would then be being asked to concatenate multiple non list objects). But because you replied in a comment it's impossible to tell.

Comment: understood - always found this comments section a bit limiting, hopefully my edit makes it easier to understand. Many thanks.

Comment: if I'm reading this right it should be: `scopes = concat(azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id,azurerm_app_service.location2.*.id)`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that should work also, but I get this error when planning: `Error: scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 4 declared`

Comment: Actaully I think this is a limitation of azurerm, it looks like it only accepts one value at the moment - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3719 and https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure/issues/449

Comment: I think what you set for the scopes is not only a list of resources ID but a list of two lists. So you can try to set the scopes as `["${azurerm_app_service.location1.*.id}"]`.

Answer (score 1):

this question is quite old, but still no answer, and I had a similar problem, so I give you the results of my research:

First, the splat expression syntax changed in terraform 0.12, so resource.*.attribute is now resource[*].attribute. This returns a list, that's why you get the "Inappropriate value" errors:

```
scopes = concat(azurerm_app_service.location1[*].id, azurerm_app_service.location2[*].id)
```

would be correct.

The other error: "scopes: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declare" is because of other required attributes, if you use more than one value for scopes. Have a look at the provider documentation of this ressource at the attributes target_resource_type and target_resource_location. These two are required if using more than one scope:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert#target_resource_type

I couldn't test this on azure, because we don't use it, but I hope it helps.